# Как добавить комбинацию клавиш для поиска всех ссылок на член класса C# Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Хочу добавить для этой кнопки горячие клавиши в Visual Studio 2022. Как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ для студии на английском, потому что руссифицированная студия на самом деле не очень полная (например в GitView не все кнопки есть)

Для начала зайдём в настройки: `Tools` -> `Options`. Во вкладке `Environment` найдём `Keyboard`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В окне `Show commands containing` напишем `reference`. Находим `Edit.FindAllReferences` и кликаем  чтобы выбрать. В текстбоксе `Press shortcut keys` биндим нужную комбинацию клавиш. Нажимаем `Ok` и вуаля. Перезапускать студию не нужно будет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]